# User Control and Session management Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, attachment

I developed an attachment control for my team.
The control is in a separate project.

**I put those attachments (documents) in session whenever I upload the files in my attachment user control.**
Only when I save, I got those attachments from the session and save in DB.

Now, my team told me that there can be two or more attachment in a page.
Since I put those in session, I can't handle it anymore.

How should I handle it ?
Using session is a bad option ? I don't know where to put those attachments before I save.

Any suggestion would be great for me.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I hope this is an intranet application. But apart from that, why is it a problem that there could be multiple attachments on one page?

Comment: No idea why there can be more than one attachment. I am in the common team, so I don't know how other team will use it .

Answer (score 1):

You should use view-state (or control state) for tracking control's state. This allows you to use same keys for state-bag across multiple instances of the same control. In your case, you should store the actual document content (file) in the temporary configurable directory with random unique name (e.g. guid) and keep this random name and original name (and more attributes if any) in the view-state. While saving, move contents from file-system to DB (and delete those files).

If you don't want to change too much of your existing code then you can continue using Session as your storage but generate session key per control instance. For example, if you are using `"MyFile"` as key to the session then start using `"MyFile_" + Control.ClientID` as key to your session data - this will allow you to have multiple instances per page.
More robust way for session key would be generate a unique key (guid) within each control instance and save this key within the view-state.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, storing the data in memory isn't probably a great idea because depending on the scenario this could badly increase your memory footprint. You could for example instead store them in a temporary folder or in a database but mark them as not being saved. You can use some identifier to tell different attachments in different sessions apart (e.g. create a sub folder named like the SessionID, or use a table with columns SessionID, FileName, Data or similar). This way it's probably easier to handle multiple attachments: if the user uploads a file, just add it to the folder/table. To list all uploaded attachments, list all files in the SessionID folder or list all database rows with the proper SessionID column.

This is just a rough sketch, as I don't know your exact scenario or requirements.